# Fork Program Please Review

Tags: c

Write a C program that sets an environment variable called done to 0.

The program will then ask the user to enter 5 numbers in a loop and store the numbers in an array of 5 int elements.

1. The  program  will  then  creates  a  clone  process  (using  fork()).
2. The  clone  should  run  a  function called sum() that calculates the total sum of all the numbers in the array.
3. After that the clone will set the done environment variable to 1. It will also create a second environment variable called result and will set it to the return value of the sum()function.
4. The parent process wait on done variable until it is set to 1.
5. If it is 1, the parent will print to the screen : The sum of elements is: result.

*Note that result is the content of the environment variable called result.*

Please note that you need to choose a suitable signature for your sum()function,
meaning that it is  up  to  you  to  decide  about  the  type  and the  number  of  arguments  as well  as  the  type  of  the return value.

I am not sure why my program is not working.

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<unistd.h>

 int sum(int a[], int size) {

    int index, result = 0;

    for (index = 0; index < size; index++) {

            result+=a[index];
            return result;
    }
}

    int main() {

            int i, array[5], result;
            long pid;
            char string[20];

            for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

                    scanf("%d", &array[i]);
                    if (i == 4) {
                    }
            }

            setenv("done", "0", 1);

            pid = fork();

            if (pid == 0) {

                    result = sum(array,5);
                    sprintf(string, "%d", result);
                    setenv("result", string, 1);
                    setenv("done","1",1);
            }

            else {
                    while (strcmp(getenv("done"), "0") == 0) {
                                                                        }

                    result = atoi(getenv("result"));
                    printf("The sum of elements is %d\n", result);

            }

            return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately separate process do not share environment, which mean your implementation would never work, use shared memory (or file) for such purpose

Comment: Rather you than me. As specified, it cannot be done sanely (and I’d remain to be convinced it could be done insanely).  A child process cannot ordinarily affect its parent process’s environment.

Answer (score 0):

This my not be the answer you desire, but 2 way communication via environment variable is near impossible because as pointed out in the comment a child process could not affect its parent process environment.

I would suggest you look at [inter process communication](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/inter-process-communication-ipc/) :

- Shared memory
- Pipe
- Socket
- RPC